# Compare two arrays and delete identical values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

My goal is to delete all identical rows from a sheet.

I created two arrays. One is the "current row" (1) and the second array is refilled with one row after the other. This part works.

Now I want to match the two arrays and if they are identical the corresponding row should be deleted.

Then the "current row" changes to 2.

```
For j = 1 To VarAnzahlZeilen
    i = 1
    For i = 1 To VarAnzahlSpalten
        ReDim Preserve ArrAktuelleZeile(i - 1) As String
        ArrAktuelleZeile(i - 1) = Worksheets("Filter").Cells(j, i).Value
    Next i

    (i+1)
    For n = j + 1 To VarAnzahlZeilen
        k = 1
        For k = 1 To VarAnzahlSpalten
             ReDim Preserve ArrDurchlaufZeile(k) As String
             ArrDurchlaufZeile(k - 1) = Worksheets("Filter").Cells(n, k).Value
        Next k

        If Not IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(ArrAktuelleZeile, ArrDurchlaufZeile, 0)) Then
            Rows(n).Delete
        End If
    Next n
Next j
```

The Runtime Error 13 appears at line:

```
If Not IsError(WorksheetFunction.Match(ArrAktuelleZeile, ArrDurchlaufZeile, 0)) Then
```

---

I tried the idea of @GTPV and modified it slightly to fit my needs (variable Range and comparing columns 1-30).

A syntax error appears

```
Worksheets("Filter").Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(VarAnzahlZeilen, VarNutzerSpalte))).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30), Header _
    :=xlNo
```

Comment: ok, what is **not** working?

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [mcve] including proper example input/output data.

Comment: I don't think the first argument in Match can be an array, you have to specify an individual element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use the built-in function from Excel which removes duplicates:

```
 Worksheets("Filter").Range("$A$1:$C$10").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 3), Header _
    :=xlNo
```

The above example will remove all duplicates in the range A1:C10 where a duplicate means "same value in column A AND same value in column C". This last parameter is controlled by the "Columns:=Array(1,3)" argument.

Getting only unique values based on column A alone would be coded as:

```
 Worksheets("Filter").Range("$A$1:$C$10").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header _
    :=xlNo
```

Getting unique values based on the combination of all columns:

```
 Worksheets("Filter").Range("$A$1:$C$10").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,2,3), Header _
    :=xlNo
```

Additional help on this function can be found [on Microsoft website.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144243)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Only note I would add, is that when possible, it's better to specify a particular sheet instead of using `ActiveSheet` (done with `Worksheets("SheetName")`, sheet code name, or by using a wroksheet object.)

Comment: @Mistella 100% agreed, I edited to match the name of the OP.